# Pushing Rails app to Heroku - PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column of relation does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to push my Rails app to Heroku but getting the following error: "PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "toilet_available" of relation "stores" does not exist"

I've then removed the "toilet_available" column from the stores table, but I'm still getting the error.

My schema looks like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180814220216) do

  create_table "stores", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "address"
    t.float "beer_cost"
    t.text "facilities"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.float "latitude"
    t.float "longitude"
    t.boolean "toilet"
    t.string "address_line2"
    t.string "address_line3"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "toilet_id"
  end

  create_table "toilets", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "toilet_available"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

Output after running heroku run rails db:migrate:

```
Running rails db:migrate on ⬢ hellospaeti... up, run.5788 (Free)
   (1.4ms)  SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(3990924734019646395)
   (1.8ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Migrating to RemoveToiletAvailableFromStores (20180627115344)
   (1.1ms)  BEGIN
== 20180627115344 RemoveToiletAvailableFromStores: migrating ==================
-- remove_column(:stores, :toilet_available, :string)
   (2.8ms)  ALTER TABLE "stores" DROP "toilet_available"
   (1.2ms)  ROLLBACK
   (1.3ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(3990924734019646395)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "toilet_available" of relation "stores" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "stores" DROP "toilet_available"
```

migration file:

```
class RemoveToiletAvailableFromStores < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    remove_column :stores, :toilet_available, :string
  end
end
```

Can't work out why it's not working and a bit worried I'm messing things up further after trying a couple of different migrations. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you migrating via release phase or manually running `heroku run rails db:migrate`? What's the log output when migrating? Do you have production data in your DB, or can you run `heroku pg:reset` to start from scratch?

Comment: yeah, i'm running heroku run rails db:migrate. There isn't too much data in the production DB so I guess I could reset it. I'll add the output to the post.

Comment: I'd go the `pg:reset` route to avoid spending too much time on this. Your DB got into an unexpected state in a previous migration, so it's hard to diagnose at this point.

Comment: My guess is what's happened here is you've edited historical migrations, so they no longer make sense to all run sequentially. In particular, perhaps you changed/removed a migration which *added* `stores.toilet_available`, and so now the later migration which removes it doesn't make sense.

Comment: You could try re-running all migrations from scratch, and add/edit/delete them to make it logical again. But this shouldn't normally be necessary, since you shouldn't normally have changed historical migrations in the first place.

Comment: (Maybe you edited the file, to change `stores.toilets_available :string` to `stores.toilet :boolean`? If it's already been merged to master / deployed to production, then don't do that. Add a new migration instead.)

Comment: I didn't change any of the migration files. Would it be possible to run a migration rollback? Or would a reset be better?

Comment: Please update your post and post the RemoveToiletAvailableFromStores file. Have you removed the associations belongs_to/has_many in the model files as well? Also, make sure you commit your project to GitHub and then to heroku, otherwise heroku will not notice any changes from your local project.

Comment: No, I haven't removed the associations. Added the file to the post now.

Comment: pg:reset doesn't change anything either

Comment: Would dropping the table and then adding it again be a viable option? Or could this cause problems?

Comment: You can see what's in the database by running `heroku pg:psql` you can then see what's in the table by running `\d stores`.

Comment: @Schneems When I try `heroku pg:psql` I get the following message, basically asking me to install postgres:

`heroku-cli: update available from 6.14.36-15f8a25 to 6.99.0-ec9edad
--> Connecting to postgresql-symmetrical-68602
 ▸    The local psql command could not be located. For help installing psql, see
 ▸    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup`

Comment: The error is telling you that you need to install a postgres driver on your local machine. Follow the directions in the link and then run the command again.

Comment: When I run `heroku pg:info` it says the PG version is 10.4, however, when i go to the windows installer, 10.4 is not available to select.

Comment: I have another app running fine in Heroku with pg database

Comment: @catinahat you don't need that exact same version locally just a version of psql. Also can you run `rake db:schema_load` successfully on the app?